# Does running help to get rid of a product put in the body by intramuscular injection?

Tags: medications, muscle, sports

I receive an intramuscular injection of Haldol (Haloperidol) every week. Does doing exercise (such as running) helps in getting rid of the injected Haldol?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! Please take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour) to the site and read the [help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help). Sharing your previous research on this might help us answer questions, if you edit those details into your question with inspiration from [how to ask](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This seems like a good question to ask your doctor; whether your dose depends on your activity level. I am puzzled by the use of the word "helps" - do you not want this medication to take effect? Why do you think getting rid of it is a good thing?